# Windows 10 1903 Intel wireless Bluetooth loses connection after few minutes

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, windows-10-v1903

I just updated to Windows 10 1903 and since then I've been having issues with my Bluetooth mouse connection. It will work fine for between 3-7 minutes (sometimes longer) then just stop responding. This is a laptop so I just use the touch pad to navigate to Bluetooth devices, turn off BT, wait, turn on BT, and my mouse starts working again for a while.

I read these links and tried an array of recent drivers from Intel, as well as their updater to no avail. Did Intel outsource their 7265 hardware to Qualcomm or Realtek?

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-after-windows-10-may-2019-update-heres-how-to-fix-it/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4507623/some-bluetooth-devices-may-fail-to-pair-or-connect-after-applying-june

My Wi-Fi is from an `Intel 7265` which I think provides the BT functionality if I'm not mistaken.

The laptop is about 4 years old, or whatever was old enough to not come with Windows 10 on it. Everything else is working fine.

Anyone else with similar issues with Intel Bluetooth?

- Update: rollback to 1809 and the issue still exists...

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate that last cumlative update you have installed on your system.

Comment: Isn't that 1903?

Comment: 1903 would be the version of Windows 10 you are running.  I am asking which cumaltive patch do you have installed.  **While you have an answer that indicates this is a known issue, it's also an issue, that was solved with the most recent cumlative patch.**  So I would still request you provide the information I asked for.

Comment: Since it was working prior to the 1903 fiasco, I decided to reinstall Windows. A bit drastic perhaps, but I'm now back to a working mouse. It is not offering 1903 yet, but I will keep an eye out for it. As far at the cumulative update, I believe it was the 2019-07, but I could be mistaken. I'm presently on 1809 with 2019-07 and working fine with latest Intel drivers.

Comment: I don't believe drivers are uninstalled (in their entireity) when you perform a rollback to a previous version.

Comment: Just making sure, but you've disabled power state changes, right?  Note that on some systems, **Windows will ignore power plan settings**, in which case you'd need to use either `gpo.msc` or `cmd` to apply.

Answer (score 0):

try using a different bluetooth device, headphones or maybe another mouse or simply try sending any files to your pc using your phones bluetooth and see if the connection stops, might be an issues with the mouse itself and not windows.

And be sure of the bluetooth provider,check your laptops manual or website to check if it might be qualcomm or atheros, realtek or anything else and make sure you have the correct drivers.This is most likely a driver issue.

If it is intel then remove the current driver and download this one:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28906/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-for-Windows-10?product=83635

Also, try replacing the batteries of your mouse.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is
[known to Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#450msgdesc):

> Microsoft has identified compatibility issues with some driver
>   versions for Bluetooth radios made by Realtek and Qualcomm. To
>   safeguard your update experience, we have applied a compatibility hold
>   on devices with affected driver versions for Realtek or Qualcomm
>   Bluetooth radios from being offered Windows 10, version 1903 or
>   Windows Server, version 1903 until the driver has been updated.
>
> **Affected platforms**:
>
> - Client: Windows 10, version 1903
> - Server: Windows Server, version 1903
>
> **Workaround**: Check with your device manufacturer (OEM) to see if an updated driver is available and install it.
>
> - For Qualcomm drivers, you will need to install a driver version greater than 10.0.1.11.
> - For Realtek drivers, you will need to install a driver version greater than 1.5.1011.0.
>
> **Note** Until an updated driver has been installed, we recommend you do not attempt to manually update using the Update now button or the
>   Media Creation Tool.

If your computer suffers from that problem, the 1903 upgrade should not have been
offered automatically via Windows Update, although it is always possible to
manually force the upgrade (did you do that?).

My advice would be to fall back to Windows 10 version 1809 until the right driver
becomes available.

For more information, see the article:
[Wi-Fi and Bluetooth not working after Windows 10 May 2019 Update](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-after-windows-10-may-2019-update-heres-how-to-fix-it/).

This article might also be useful:
[How to block the Windows 10 May 2019 Update, version 1903, from installing](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3232632/how-to-block-the-windows-10-may-2019-update-version-1903-from-installing.html).

Comment: Does Qualcomm or Realtek make the Intel hardware and thus the Intel hardware is affected by this product. I figured that since it was offering the update (without a manual check) then my laptop was "ready" for the update.

Comment: Microsoft usually gets the driver from the manufacturer, although the manufacturer might have newer drivers on its website. In my experience, Windows might be several months behind, perhaps because of quality assurance. If the manufacturer's driver does not work for you, then Windows Update made a mistake in offering the 1903 update. I suggest addressing the Support of Qualcomm or Realtek, and if no satisfactory answer then roll back to Windows 1809.

Comment: So is it confirmed that my `Intel 7265 chipset` is affected by a Qualcomm or Realtek driver issue? It was my understanding that Intel does its own wireless chipsets, and as such, shouldn't be affected by this issue. Please provide some details indicating that an Intel chipset is affected by a Qualcomm or Realtek product driver.

Comment: The above linked article summarizes the problems reported by the readers of `techrepublic.com`, and this is acknowledged in the above Microsoft link. There is no way for me to know if your specific adapter is affected, but what else could it be?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree it might be related, but I would have expected specific mention of Intel hardware if it were affected given its popularity.

Comment: The only way to check is if the roll back to 1809 fixes the problem ;) Just note that you only have 28 days for doing that.

Comment: I rolled back and updated the Bluetooth driver, and it still offers the update. I guess I'll wait a while to see if the connection drops again.

Comment: Well, I just had the issue again on 1809, so that makes me think it is a separate issue. I got to Windows 10 from a Windows 8.1 update, so maybe I'll try Windows 10 1809 from scratch to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Another try is to delete the device and reboot to see if the generic driver can do better.

Comment: Already tried that. I always thinks it is fixed until it just stops. All my recent stuff has been on 1809 including the same drop outs, so if it is in fact related, the rollback didn't fix everything.

Comment: @harrymc - The Bluetooth issue with 1903 was fixed with the June 27th 2019 cumaltive patch.

Comment: @Ramhound: AFAIK the poster was supposed to have that patch, it's now July.

Comment: When deleting the device, did you also delete the driver? And why the downvote?

Comment: @harrymc - There wasn't a 1903 cumaltive patch released last week.  The author could also have cumaltive patches on a small delay.  Which is the reason I asked about which cumaltive patch they installed.  **Intel makes it's own radios, the issue is specifically with Realtek and Qualcomm BT radios.** The downvote is due to the fact, the issue does not apply to the author, based on the fact the problem is with an Intel BT device.  If my internet was not hit or miss I would have asked for additional contents hours ago.

Comment: I have that upgrade installed, so my assumption was perhaps too hasty. Dear poster: See if you have it by running "View installed updates" and sorting by the "Installed On" column in reverse order. If not, see if Windows Update doesn't list it.